# Regex Only Letters One Capital Letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that allows only letters with at least one capital question, without numbers.

I have came up with `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).+$/` but I can not negate the numbers.

Comment: Can you give an example of text that it should match and text that it shouldn't match?

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*$/
```

Try it here:http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=96373